# BaseX GUI Command Bar Error Unknown Command

Tags: basex

I occassionally use BaseX GUI for examining XML files and trying XSL transforms.  I don't know what has happened but I can no longer run one-liners in the Command/Find/XQuery bar that sits below the toolbar.  I always get "Error unknown command try help".  The drop down has recently used commands none of which work any longer.[image]

I have tried upgrading BaseX from 9.3 to 9.7 and upgrading java. I'm running windows 10.  My searching didn't yield any results, I hoping someone can help because I'm out of ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you change the "command" dropdown to "xquery"?

Comment: **It does!**  For the xslt:transform-text function I had specify the full paths to the xml and xslt files (rather than the relative paths to the working directory) but that's all.  That's great @Andy Bunce thank you, if you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.  Do you know why it isn't working in "Command" mode - I'm assuming it used to because I had such a big list of commands in the most recently used dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries shown in your [inputbar](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Graphical_User_Interface#Input_Bar) image are XQuery expressions, with the exception of `help` which is a command. So changing the mode dropdown from `Command` to `XQuery` will enable them to run.

Note: modes `XQuery` and `Find` require an open database.

It looks like your XQuery expressions are not database specific so as an alternative you could leave the mode as `Command` and prefix your text with the command 'XQUERY '  eg `XQUERY 1+3` etc

Comment: Works for me. Thanks for the XQUERY prefix tip.  Odd though, I'm sure it used to work in `Command` mode.